# Reference request: well-posedness of nonlinear Schrödinger and relativistic Schrödinger equations?

Tags: reference-request, mathematical-physics

I have been trying to find a book that covers the well-posedness of non-linear equations that appear in theoretical physics such as the Schrödinger, Klein-Gordon, and Dirac equations without much success. While there are plenty of books on dispersive PDEs in general (like [this one](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4939-2181-2) for example) on the well-posedness of non-linear Schrödinger equations, relativistic equations seem to be much neglected. If anyone knows if there are any good references on this subject I would much appreacite if they could share it.

Comment: Try Evan's PDEs text.

Comment: Thank you! I guess I had never checked Part III, which throughly covers the analysis of the Klein-Gordon equation. Still no Dirac equation, though, right?

Comment: Turns out I found the Dirac equation and some spinor material in Wald's "General Relativity" text. That one is a great read altogether, but requires a ton of diff geo background.